# Grand Fantasia Invisible Characters

Tags: 15.04, wine, playonlinux

I've recently upgraded from Ubuntu 14.04 to Ubuntu 15.04 (Vivid Vervet) and I'm busy installing some programs and games I had running on Ubuntu 14.04.

I was installing Grand Fantasia, everything went well, except for the fact that my characters were invisible. I had experienced this earlier too, on Ubuntu 14.04, but at that time, I fixed it by adding three DWORD-values in the registry: MaxShaderModelGS, MaxShaderModelPS and MaxShaderModelVS (all of them had value 0).

However, this time, it didn't fix the problem. At first, I tried adding some other strings to the registry, but nothing seemed to work. I also tried googling for a bit, but I couldn't find anything that worked for me.

Does anybody know how to fix this problem?

I use Wine 1.7.46 and PlayOnLinux 4.2.9 on Ubuntu 15.04 (Vivid Vervet)

Thanks in advance,

Regards, Rutgervdp

Comment: 1) Install new Wine. 2) Try adding the native DX/other DLLs into Wine. 3) Try installing old Wine. 4) Try messing with those settings. - If those don't work, either go back to 14.04, or you can just use Xen and virtualize a GPU (you need two GPUs for this).

Comment: Hello Shiki, thanks for your quick response! I tried messing with the settings when I came across the "registry edit" button in PlayOnLinux. I clicked it and I discovered that I had added the strings in the registry of the system-wine version instead of the wine1.7.46. I added it in the registry of my GrandFantasia Virtual Drive in POL and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems to be very specific to this game. Always consult Wine's application database in https://appdb.winehq.org/ before installing any new programs through Wine. If there are problems, AppDB will probably have a workaround.